# Why need to decrease clientHeight from windowHeight while calculating scrollPercent?

Tags: javascript, scroll, window

I am trying to show how much a user has scrolled through the page a with progress bar and I have done it.  But I have a little confusion here.

Here is the code that I found to calculate  `scrollPercent` which works well

```
windowHeight = Math.max(
html.clientHeight,
html.scrollHeight,
html.offsetHeight,
body.scrollHeight,
body.offsetHeight
);

const  scrolledPercent =
((html.scrollTop || body.scrollTop) / (windowHeight - html.clientHeight)) *
100;
```

Initially, I thought, to get the `scrollPercent` , I need to get the current `scrollPosition` and divide that number with the total height of the page and multiply by `100%` . which is like normally how we get `%` of something.

```
const  scrolledPercent = 
((html.scrollTop || body.scrollTop) / windowHeight) * 100;
```

but this line doesnot worked as I expected . If I do this the progress bar wont reach `100%` even if I scroll to end of the page. I don't understand why am I wrong here !

So, my question is why do we need to decrease the `html.clientHeight`  from  `windowHeight` ?

Thank you.

Demo here:

```js
// --------------------------------------------
// variables
// --------------------------------------------

const html = document.documentElement,
  body = document.body,
  countryList = document.querySelector(".country__list");
scrollNavigated = document.querySelector(".scroll__navigated");
let windowHeight;

// --------------------------------------------
// function
// --------------------------------------------

async function prepareListOfCountries() {
  let list = await fetch("https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all");
  list = Array.from(await list.json());
  let markup = list
    .map((country, index) => {
      return `<li class="country__item card">
              <span class="country__name">${country.name}</span
              ><span class="country__capital">${country.capital}</span>
              <a href="javascript:;" class="country__flag">
               <img src= '${country.flag}'> </a>
             
        </li>`;
    })
    .slice(0, 30)
    .join(" ");
  countryList.innerHTML = markup;
}

function updateScrolledStatus(e) {
  windowHeight = Math.max(
    html.clientHeight,
    html.scrollHeight,
    html.offsetHeight,
    body.scrollHeight,
    body.offsetHeight
  );

  const scrolledPercent =
    ((html.scrollTop || body.scrollTop) / (windowHeight - html.clientHeight)) *
    100;
  // const scrolledPercent =
  //   ((html.scrollTop || body.scrollTop) / windowHeight) * 100; // this line doesnot work
  scrollNavigated.style.width = scrolledPercent + "%";
}

prepareListOfCountries();

// --------------------------------------------
// event-handler
// --------------------------------------------

window.addEventListener("scroll", updateScrolledStatus);
```

```css
*::after,
*::before,
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background: #fff;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Oxygen,
 Ubuntu, Cantarell, "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
}

.container {
  max-width: 980px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.justify-between {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.items-center {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.card {
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 12px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.054);
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 16px;
}

.country__flag img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.header {
  padding: 24px 0;
  background-color: #333;
  color: #f1f1f1;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
}

.content {
  padding: 50px 0;
}

.content__form {
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 32px;
}

.content__search {
  width: 50%;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  transition: 0.2s;
}

.content__search:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 1px 6px 0 rgba(32, 33, 36, 0.28);
}

.content__search:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.country__list {
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin: 10px auto;
}

.country__item {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
}

.country__name, .country__capital, .country__flag {
  width: 33.33%;
}

.country__flag {
  width: 32px;
  height: 24px;
}

.scroll__navigator {
  height: 2px;
  margin: 0 auto 32px;
  background-color: #333;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

.scroll__navigated {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  background: orangered;
  transition: 0.3s linear;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <header class="header">
      <div class="container">
        All countries list
      </div>
    </header>
    <main class="content">
      <div class="container">
        <form class="content__form">
          <input class="content__search" />
        </form>
        <div class="scroll__navigator">
          <span class="scroll__navigated"></span>
        </div>
        <section class="country">
          <ul class="country__list">
            <li class="country__item card">
              <span class="country__name">Nepal</span
              ><span class="country__capital">Kathmandu</span>
              <a href="javascript:;" class="country__flag"></a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </section>
      </div>
    </main>
     
  </body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an example, say that the height of your client is `100px` and the height of your whole page is `500px`.

When the scroll position is `0px`, you're able to see the first `100px` of your site, so from `0px` to `100px`.

At scroll position `100px`, you can see the range `100px` to `200px`, because you've moved the page, and therefore the visible range, on by `100px`.

At scroll position `400px`, you can therefore see the range `400px` to `500px` – in other words, you've scrolled to the bottom.

This demonstrates that the scrollable height of the page (`400px`) is less than the actual height of the page (`500px`), namely by the height of the client.

To get the percentage scrolled, you need to use the scrollable height, so it is necessary to subtract the height of the client from the height of the page to get a correct value, or you'll never be able to scroll to the bottom. It's not possible to scroll by `500px` on a site that is only `500px` long!

Comment: Thank you. I got it.